Is a plane a cylindrical surface?
Just a quick question regarding planes and cylindrical surfaces.
According to James Stewart's Calculus: Early Trascendentals book (section 12.6), "a cylinder is a surface that consists of all lines (called rulings) that are parallel to a given line and pass through a given plane curve."
The same book starts the section with: "We have already looked at two special types of surfaces — planes and spheres. Here we investigate two other types of surfaces — cylinders and quadric surfaces.". So, a distinction is made between "plane" and "cylinder".
My question is: wouldn't a plane be a cylindrical surface according to this definition? For example, the xy-plane is formed by all lines parallel to a given line (the x-axis) and pass through a given plane curve (the y-axis).
Thanks in advance for your help!

Perhaps the different 'types' of surfaces are not mutually exclusive. That is, planes are cylinders, under this definition, and it is just OK. It would be interesting to see what is the author's definition for 'plane curve'.

@ajotatxe Thanks for your answer. The author doesn't give a definition of 'plane curve', but by context I understand that he means a curve contained in a plane.

I suspect Stewart's intent was to describe a cylinder as constructed from a curve in a plane by taking the union of all the lines through that curve parallel to a given line not in that plane.
Since that isn't explicitly stated, when you read Stewart's definition literally, with no context, a plane is a cylinder.

Thanks for your answer. I think you meant cylinder and not cone, right? Well, I agree and also I don't have a problem with a plane being considered a cylinder. It was just curiosity :-)

You're welcome. Changed "cone" to "cylinder" - but there's a comparable natural generalization. A cone would be formed of lines through a point outside the plane. If that point were "at infinity" in the sense of projective geometry you'd have a cylinder.

If you replace “not in that plane” by “in that plane” you get a degenerate cylinder, so I think it’s safe to say Stewart had your interpretation in mind.
